# Spring State machine not changing state for some events

Tags: spring, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I have just started working on this topic. I have tried to integrate spring state machine with Spring web MVC application, in which I am sending events from a controller.

My problem is that, machine is tranitioning for some events while for some events it is not. I tried to print the log. There I can see the event generic message getting queued but transition is not happening. Please help!

I am giving a part of my log here-

`2016-01-06 12:51:32 DEBUG AbstractStateMachine:557 - Queue event GenericMessage [payload=LOGIN_CLICKED, headers={timestamp=1452064892305, id=1e223e37-4eb3-95e4-ec32-8447d57616f5}]`

Here LOGIN_CLICKED is my event, that should take my machine from WAITING_USER_INPUT state to LOGIN_PAGE state. But its not happening.

Here are all the relevant files:

**States.java**

```
package com.psl.model;

public enum States {

    START, WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT, LOGIN_PAGE, SIGNUP_PAGE, CUSTOMER_AUTHENTICATED, CUSTOMER_SIGNEDUP, APPLICATION_UI_PAGE, END

}
```

**Events.java**

```
package com.psl.model;

public enum Events {

    INITIAL_TRANSITION, LOGIN_CLICKED, SIGNUP_CLICKED, USER_NOT_FOUND, USER_FOUND, VALIDATION_FAIL, VALIDATION_SUCCESS, GO_HOME, LOG_OUT

}
```

**StateMachineConfig.java**

```
package com.psl.statemachine;

import java.util.EnumSet;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.EnableStateMachine;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineStateConfigurer;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineTransitionConfigurer;

import com.psl.model.Events;
import com.psl.model.States;

@Configuration
@EnableStateMachine
public class StateMachineConfig extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<States, Events>{

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<States, Events> states)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        states.withStates().initial(States.START).states(EnumSet.allOf(States.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(
            StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<States, Events> transitions)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        transitions
        .withExternal().source(States.START).target(States.WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT).event(Events.INITIAL_TRANSITION).and()
        .withExternal().source(States.WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT).target(States.LOGIN_PAGE).event(Events.LOGIN_CLICKED).and()
        .withExternal().source(States.WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT).target(States.SIGNUP_PAGE).event(Events.SIGNUP_CLICKED).and()
        .withExternal().source(States.LOGIN_PAGE).target(States.LOGIN_PAGE).event(Events.USER_NOT_FOUND).and()
        .withExternal().source(States.SIGNUP_PAGE).target(States.SIGNUP_PAGE).event(Events.VALIDATION_FAIL).and()
        .withExternal().source(States.LOGIN_PAGE).target(States.CUSTOMER_AUTHENTICATED).event(Events.USER_FOUND).and()
        .withExternal().source(States.SIGNUP_PAGE).target(States.CUSTOMER_SIGNEDUP).event(Events.VALIDATION_SUCCESS).and()
        .withExternal().source(States.CUSTOMER_AUTHENTICATED).target(States.APPLICATION_UI_PAGE).event(Events.GO_HOME).and()
        .withExternal().source(States.CUSTOMER_SIGNEDUP).target(States.APPLICATION_UI_PAGE).event(Events.GO_HOME).and()
        .withExternal().source(States.APPLICATION_UI_PAGE).target(States.END).event(Events.LOG_OUT);

        /*transitions
        .withExternal().source(States.START).target(States.WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT).event(Events.INITIAL_TRANSITION).and()
        .withExternal().source(States.WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT).target(States.LOGIN_PAGE).event(Events.LOGIN_CLICKED).and()
        .withExternal().source(States.LOGIN_PAGE).target(States.CUSTOMER_AUTHENTICATED).event(Events.USER_FOUND).and()
        .withExternal().source(States.CUSTOMER_AUTHENTICATED).target(States.APPLICATION_UI_PAGE).event(Events.GO_HOME).and()
        .withExternal().source(States.APPLICATION_UI_PAGE).target(States.END).event(Events.LOG_OUT);*/

        /*transitions
        .withExternal().source(States.START).target(States.WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT).event(Events.INITIAL_TRANSITION).and()
        .withExternal().source(States.WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT).target(States.SIGNUP_PAGE).event(Events.SIGNUP_CLICKED).and()
        .withExternal().source(States.SIGNUP_PAGE).target(States.CUSTOMER_SIGNEDUP).event(Events.VALIDATION_SUCCESS).and()
        .withExternal().source(States.CUSTOMER_SIGNEDUP).target(States.APPLICATION_UI_PAGE).event(Events.GO_HOME).and()
        .withExternal().source(States.APPLICATION_UI_PAGE).target(States.END).event(Events.LOG_OUT).and()
        .withExternal().source(States.END).target(States.WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT).event(Events.INITIAL_TRANSITION);*/

    }

}
```

**OnTransitionActions.java**

```
package com.psl.statemachine;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.statemachine.annotation.OnTransition;
import org.springframework.statemachine.annotation.WithStateMachine;

@WithStateMachine
public class OnTransitionActions {

    static final Logger LOGGER2 = Logger.getLogger("stateMachineLogFile");

    @OnTransition(source = "START", target = "WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT")
    public void method1(){
        LOGGER2.info("Transition: START -> WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT");
        LOGGER2.info("Current State: WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT");

        System.out.println("*********************Current State: WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT*********************");
    }

    @OnTransition(source = "WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT", target = "LOGIN_PAGE")
    public void method2(){
        LOGGER2.info("Transition: WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT -> LOGIN_PAGE");
        LOGGER2.info("Current State: LOGIN_PAGE");

        System.out.println("*********************Current State: LOGIN_PAGE*********************");
    }

    @OnTransition(source = "WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT", target = "SIGNUP_PAGE")
    public void method3(){
        LOGGER2.info("Transition: WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT -> SIGNUP_PAGE");
        LOGGER2.info("Current State: SIGNUP_PAGE");

        System.out.println("*********************Current State: SIGNUP_PAGE*********************");
    }

    @OnTransition(source = "LOGIN_PAGE", target = "LOGIN_PAGE")
    public void method4(){
        LOGGER2.info("Transition: LOGIN_PAGE -> LOGIN_PAGE");
        LOGGER2.info("Current State: LOGIN_PAGE");

        System.out.println("*********************Current State: LOGIN_PAGE*********************");
    }

    @OnTransition(source = "SIGNUP_PAGE", target = "SIGNUP_PAGE")
    public void method5(){
        LOGGER2.info("Transition: SIGNUP_PAGE -> SIGNUP_PAGE");
        LOGGER2.info("Current State: SIGNUP_PAGE");

        System.out.println("*********************Current State: SIGNUP_PAGE*********************");
    }

    @OnTransition(source = "LOGIN_PAGE", target = "CUSTOMER_AUTHENTICATED")
    public void method6(){
        LOGGER2.info("Transition: LOGIN_PAGE -> CUSTOMER_AUTHENTICATED");
        LOGGER2.info("Current State: CUSTOMER_AUTHENTICATED");

        System.out.println("*********************Current State: CUSTOMER_AUTHENTICATED*********************");
    }


    @OnTransition(source = "SIGNUP_PAGE", target = "CUSTOMER_SIGNEDUP")
    public void method7(){
        LOGGER2.info("Transition: SIGNUP_PAGE -> CUSTOMER_SIGNEDUP");
        LOGGER2.info("Current State: CUSTOMER_SIGNEDUP");

        System.out.println("*********************Current State: CUSTOMER_SIGNEDUP*********************");
    }


    @OnTransition(source = "CUSTOMER_AUTHENTICATED", target = "APPLICATION_UI_PAGE")
    public void method8(){
        LOGGER2.info("Transition: CUSTOMER_AUTHENTICATED -> APPLICATION_UI_PAGE");
        LOGGER2.info("Current State: APPLICATION_UI_PAGE");

        System.out.println("*********************Current State: APPLICATION_UI_PAGE*********************");
    }

    @OnTransition(source = "CUSTOMER_SIGNEDUP", target = "APPLICATION_UI_PAGE")
    public void method9(){
        LOGGER2.info("Transition: CUSTOMER_SIGNEDUP -> APPLICATION_UI_PAGE");
        LOGGER2.info("Current State: APPLICATION_UI_PAGE");

        System.out.println("*********************Current State: APPLICATION_UI_PAGE*********************");
    }

    @OnTransition(source = "APPLICATION_UI_PAGE", target = "END")
    public void method10(){
        LOGGER2.info("Transition: APPLICATION_UI_PAGE -> END");
        LOGGER2.info("Current State: END");

        System.out.println("*********************Current State: END*********************");
    }

    @OnTransition(source = "END", target = "WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT")
    public void method11(){
        LOGGER2.info("Transition: END -> WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT");
        LOGGER2.info("Current State: WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT");

        System.out.println("*********************Current State: WAITING_CUSTOMER_INPUT*********************");
    }

}
```

**RunStateMachine.java**

```
package com.psl.statemachine;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.statemachine.StateMachine;

import com.psl.model.Events;
import com.psl.model.States;

public class RunStateMachine {

    @Autowired
    StateMachine<States, Events> stateMachine;

    @Bean
    public StateMachineEventListener stateMachineEventListener(){
        StateMachineEventListener stateMachineEventListener = new StateMachineEventListener();
        stateMachine.addStateListener(stateMachineEventListener);
        return stateMachineEventListener;
    }

    public void fireEvent(Events event){
        stateMachine.start();
        stateMachine.sendEvent(event);

        /*
         * stateMachine.stop();
        if(event == Events.LOG_OUT)
            stateMachine.stop();*/
    }

}
```

I am sending events via **RunStateMachine.java** as shown above. I am calling the   *fireEvent*   method from my MVC controller like this:

**LoginController.java**

```
package com.psl.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.psl.dao.IUserDao;
import com.psl.model.Events;
import com.psl.statemachine.RunStateMachine;

@Controller
@Scope(value = "session")
public class LoginController {

    static final Logger LOGGER1 = Logger.getLogger("appLogFile");

    //Creating bean for RunStateMachine class
    private ApplicationContext statemachine_context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("statemachine-config.xml");
    RunStateMachine machine = (RunStateMachine) statemachine_context.getBean("runStateMachine");


    private ApplicationContext jdbc_context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "spring-jdbc-config.xml");

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model model){

        //sending event to the machine
        machine.fireEvent(Events.LOGIN_CLICKED);

        return "LoginPage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String manuallyProcessLogin(HttpServletRequest request){

        //get from form
        String name = request.getParameter("username");
        String pass = request.getParameter("password");
        LOGGER1.info("Username = " + name + "\nPassword = " + pass);

        //check into database
        IUserDao dao = (IUserDao) jdbc_context.getBean("dao");
        boolean ifAuth = dao.authenticateUser(name, pass);


        LOGGER1.info("*****************LOGIN POST METHOD**************");
        if(ifAuth){
            machine.fireEvent(Events.USER_FOUND);
            //statemachine.sendEvent(Events.USER_FOUND);
            String uname = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
            if(uname == null){
                //add new uname
                request.getSession().setAttribute("user", name);
            }
            return "LoginSuccess";
        }

        machine.fireEvent(Events.USER_NOT_FOUND);
        return "LoginPage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

        //manually logout
        request.getSession().invalidate();

        machine.fireEvent(Events.LOG_OUT);

        return "LogoutSuccess";
    }

}
```

Here is the state machine configuration file:

**statemachine-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.psl.statemachine"></context:component-scan>
        <bean id="runStateMachine" class="com.psl.statemachine.RunStateMachine" scope="singleton"></bean>

    </beans>
```

Here is the **web.xml**, where I declare custom filter for spring security, that filters and sends all requests for **`/Welcome`** to **`/Login`** in the controller above:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Manually apply filter for security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>manualSecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.psl.filters.ManualSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>manualSecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/Welcome</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

**UPDATE: SOLVED!!** 
Just figured out that multiple MVC Controllers are not working for State Machine!!! When I put all my RequestMapping methods in 1 controller, it worked.

Comment: Impossible to answer without full machine config.

Comment: @Janne sorry for that. Please refer to the edited post. Please tell me if you need anything more. Also - Spring version used: 4.2.4.RELEASE, State Machine version used: 1.0.2.RELEASE

Comment: Don't create new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext in controller, instead autowire machine.

Comment: Thanks for posting update. I encountered the same problem with MVC and statemachine.